# What are "targeted supplies"?

Tags: international-trade

From *New geopolitics of natural gas*:

the policy of assisting friends can include price discounts, [targeted supplies] , or financial or technological support to develop energy resources for partner nations.

Comment: Perhaps this might describe [Russia building a pipeline through the Baltic Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_Stream) so that it can sell gas to Germany without having to use the existing networks in Poland or Ukraine

Comment: The statement you quote has a footnote which refers to "Pascual, *The New Geopolitics of Energy*, 10-11". You'll probably need to track that down to know exactly what it means.